# ajax CalendarExtender return system's datetime format

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, calendar, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I need system's datetime format using Ajax calendar extender. so when I change my system's datetime format at that time calendar extender also return datetime in system's format. I tried some code but didn't get required result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CultureInfo It's possible for me to get date time in system's datetime format.

```
    string sysFormat = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
            CalendarExtender1.Format = sysFormat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code In AjaxCalanderControl.`Format` property to change as you required.

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="txt_dt_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" PopupButtonID="txt_dt" TargetControlID="txt_dt" Format="dd-MM-yyyy" CssClass="cal_Theme1"></asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use format property to desired output

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="txtDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" runat="server">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

and you can also handle on code behind.